# A workaround for C++/CLI intellisense and System namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

I have been working with standard C++ on Visual Studio for a while, and now I decided to try writing applications. I encountered the problem that in Windows Forms Applications intellisense was **"Unavailable for C++/CLI"**. So I looked up what could be done and I found I could disable **"\clr"** from the options. So I did that.

Now the compiler complains that the `using namespace System;` directive fails at finding the namespace System.

Now, uncle Google seems to tell everyone to turn back on the \clr support which I am trying to avoid.

So my question is, where does the namespace live in, so that I can include its header or some other workaround so I can work with the little intellisense left by MS and live with it, as a tool such a Visual Assist is only for free for a limited time.

Thanks, and sorry if the question is disturbingly simplistic

Answer (score 2):

`System` is a .NET Framework namespace and therefore will require the CLR option when compiling source that uses it.

Are you looking for `using namespace std` for command line applications?

Comment: No, I'm well aware of std namespace, I was hoping there was another way to add whatever file contains the System namespace, I figured it could be a header or a DLL that was automatically included by checking the CLR option

Answer (score 1):

You will need the `/CLR` (forward slash) option on to use the .NET frameworks.  Visual Studio 2008 has better (not perfect, but livable) Intellisense for C++/CLI.  If you don't need any newer features, that might be a better option for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was just hoping that the System namespace could be found in a header or in a DLL that was automatically included somewhere by the /CLR option. I guess I'll look into 2008, but I really hate when windows has their users downgrade because of lack of support...

Comment: @GettnDer I think most of it's within `mscorlib.dll` but I'd have to look it up.  The 2008 Express Edition would work just fine, no need to get the full version of VS for C++/CLI.